# Unable to close Session Factory, getting below exception while doing so

Tags: java, hibernate

```
    ModuleDAO data = new ModuleDAO();

    data.setFirstName("asd2sedd");
    data.setLastName("Lasst");

    Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(ModuleDAO.class);

    ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(con.getProperties()).build();

    SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory(registry);

    Session session = sf.openSession();

    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(data);

    t.commit();

    sf.close();
```

Databse is Mysql & it is running on the same box with default port

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

Exception Message:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

Comment: It would be great if you could post an answer along with advice @DonatasD

Comment: It's probably happening because the remote peer is closing the connection immediately not sending the last close_notify.  Actually sending close_notify message is not madatory in SSL..
can you share the datasource url???? you can hide ip

Comment: @TahirHussainMir This is the connection url i am using jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Automation

Comment: make it like this and reply back if it worked 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Automation?useSSL=false